# Escaping Queries with Options parameter for Joins with overlapping column names

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

The documentation for node-mysql on npm (https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) has an option for overlapping column names in table joins that looks like this:

```
var options = {sql: '...', nestTables: true};
connection.query(options, function(err, results) {
  /* results will be an array like this now:
  [{
    table1: {
      fieldA: '...',
      fieldB: '...',
    },
    table2: {
      fieldA: '...',
      fieldB: '...',
    },
  }, ...]
  */
});
```

**Escaping query identifiers** format passes a second param to the `connection.query()` that sanitizes the identifiers:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [userId], function(err, results) {
  // ...
});
```

I'm wondering how you can use these two together? Say you need to escape identifiers in a join, but want to declare the options for nested tables:

```
var sqlString: 'SELECT * FROM TableOne INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.id = TableTwo.tableone_id WHERE TableOne.id = ?';
var options = {sql: sqlString, nestTables: true};
connection.query(options, function(err, results) {
    ...
});
```

I attempted to pass the escape values as the second param in the `connection.query()` like so:

```
var sqlString: 'SELECT * FROM TableOne INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.id = TableTwo.tableone_id WHERE TableOne.id = ?';
    var options = {sql: sqlString, nestTables: true};
    connection.query(options, 1, function(err, results) {
        ...
    });
```

But to no avail.  I'm wondering if there is anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the code, line 66 there's an IF block

```
if (typeof sql === 'object') {
  options = sql;
  cb      = values;
  values  = options.values;
}
```

meaning you would do

```
var sqlString: 'SELECT * FROM TableOne INNER JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.id = TableTwo.tableone_id WHERE TableOne.id = ?';
var options = {sql: sqlString, nestTables: true, values: [1]};
connection.query(options, function(err, results) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: I know this is stale, but I came across it while looking for a quick answer, then decided to post my solution.